# cant @ people on discord using requests

Tags: python, python-requests, discord

```
import requests

header = {
    'authorization': 'my authorization not giving you it'
}
payload = {
    'content': ".rob @myfriends discord "
}
rob = requests.post("the discords url also not giving it", data=payload, headers=header)
```

I am using requests to and discord dev mod to get the url to the discord that all works fine but when I try to @ anyone it will just put it as plan text and does not @ them pls help so I can rob my friend on discord through the gamble bot

Comment: what is @  ?  are you want to mention people?

Comment: the @ would be anyone on discord so yeah mention people

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `@` with the user ID, and not the display name or username that your friends have. You can get the user ID by right-clicking a user and selecting "Copy ID".

I have tested that this would work.

```
payload = {
    'content': ".rob <@!172002275412279296> discord"
}
```

I also recommend using [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead if you plan to do future development, it has a lot of inbuilt stuff so that you don't have to implement from scratch.